# help with multivariable control loop

Tags: control, control-system

I am looking to find the transfer function from w to z in this loop. I have been trying for a while looking all the relationships but just don't know how to express w in terms of r,d and n and then express it as a TF with z. I would appreciate a hint on how to solve this.

[image: control loop]

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic equations
$$ z = -r + G u + d $$
$$ u = K v $$
$$ v = r -(n + z + r)) = - n - z$$

Therefore
$$ z = - r + G K (-n -z) + d$$
$$ (1 + G K) z = d - r - G K n$$
$$ z = \frac{1}{1+ G K} d + \frac{-1}{1+ G K} r + \frac{-G K}{1+ G K} n$$

The transfer function from \$w =\{d, r, n\}^T\$ to z is a 1x3 matrix

$$ \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{1+ G K} & \frac{-1}{1+ G K} &  \frac{-G K}{1+ G K} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start: -

[image]

You should be able to follow this.

Comment: Andy, thanks for your help, I also reached that point, what I don't understand is how to include w from there as I have to put the TF between z and w. My doubt is: is it w = r+d+n?

Comment: W is unspecified in your question so I cannot tell you how w relates to the three variables.